# select input value from request

Tags: html, jsp, jakarta-ee

I am currently working on my first web application. Users need to fill a form, and one of the information is 'city', as a select type input. If  the user chooses a city but one of the information is not valid, I would like the chosen city to stay there while the user fixes the invalid input.

For example, I did it for a date that the user needs to enter:

```
<input type=date name="endDate" value="<c:out value="${requete.endDate}"/>">
```

And it's working, but for a select type input I don't know how to do it..

```
<select name="city">
    <option value="City" selected>City</option>
    <option value="Ottawa">Ottawa</option>
    <option value="Toronto">Toronto</option>
    <option value="Montreal">Montreal</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The same sort of thing - let's say that the selected city is stored in request.city.

You would need to make sure that the selected option has the "selected" property in your JSP like so:

```
<select name="city">
    <option value="City" 
        <c:if test="${empty request.city}">selected</c:if>>
        City
    </option>
    <option value="Ottawa" 
        <c:if test="${request.city == 'Ottawa'}">selected</c:if>>
        Ottawa
    </option>
    <option value="Toronto" 
        <c:if test="${request.city == 'Toronto'}">selected</c:if>>
        Toronto
    </option>
    <option value="Montreal" 
        <c:if test="${request.city == 'Montreal'}">selected</c:if>>
        Montreal
    </option>
</select>
```

So, to sum up what this is doing - whatever is between a "c:if" element will only be output as HTML if the test evaluates to true. So all this test does is determine whether the selected city equals the value that option represents, and adds the "selected" property to that element if so.

Answer (score 1):

Try with simple `EL` and `selected` attribute:

```
<select name="city">
    <option value="City" selected>City</option>
    <option value="Ottawa" ${'Ottawa' eq param.city ? 'selected' : ''}>Ottawa</option>
    <option value="Toronto" ${'Toronto' eq param.city ? 'selected' : ''}>Toronto</option>
    <option value="Montreal" ${'Montreal' eq param.city ? 'selected' : ''}>Montreal</option>
</select>
```